# I need to connect a ComponetA Signal to a method of another ComponentB

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

i need to create a **ComponentC** dynamically when a button of **ComponentA** is clicked and the **ComponentC** must be created in **ComponentB** that is not accessible through id from **ComponentA**.

So how is this realisable with QML ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A signal can return an object returned by the called slot:

```
int B::slot() {
  return 12;
}

void A::test() {
  connect( this, SIGNAL(sig()), objectB, SLOT(slot());
  int i = emit sig(); // i should be equal to 12
}
```

But, I don't know if it's an expected behavior...

Comment: Sorry i don't mentioned that i'm only using Qt QML Module.